# How to connect separate UI files created by Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyqt5, pyuic

I have created a GUI application in python using PyQt5.

The steps are first I have created a ui file in Qt Designer. Then I converted that ui file into a py file using `pyuic4 -o demo.ui -x demo.py` in a terminal. After that I modify the py file to get dynamic values from a database. But when I have a little change in design, again I am creating the ui file, and again coverting to a py file and writing the code for the database.

So it takes a lot of time to repeat the same process. Are there any options for converting a py file to a ui file? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the .ui file in your python script using the following command :

```
loadUi('demo.ui', self)
```

There is some related examples in the folder named 'pyuic' of pyqt examples.

Comment: Thanks for replying .I can load ui file in python script.But is it possible to retrive database values in ui file?

Comment: I suggest you create a new question dedicated to your need with your code and a description of your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** modify the modules generated by `pyuic`. They are meant to be static modules that are imported into your main application.

The ui module should be created like this:

```
pyuic5 -o mainwindwow.py mainwindow.ui
```

And the main application file should look like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Further information can be found in the PyQt5 docs - see [Using Qt Designer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).